# Number of occurences in a CPLEX matrix column

Tags: cplex

I'm looking for a way to set a limit for the times a particular value, is included in a matrixes columns. In the current instance, I want to tell CPLEX to make sure that value 3, occurs at least one time in each of my matrix's columns.
I have been struggling with **count** function since last night with no results. Documentations are not helpfull either...

Comment: Include some code please. Have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Does 'count'  work with MILP formulations? Might need to use CP.?